# Is it possible to solve analytically $x^4+x^2+\cos x=0$

Tags: trigonometry

For the equation $x^4+x^2+\cos x=0$, it is possible to solve it analytically? If not, which numerical method can I employ to find its root(s)?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure this has a solution?

Comment: According to wolfram, it has two solutions. This one and another $sin(x^x)=1$ is found in my book. For that guy, I think there is no way I can solve it analytically. I am not sure for this guy.

Comment: $x^4+x^2=-\cos(x)$ means that $\cos(x)\le 0$ which means $|x|\ge\frac{\pi}{2}\gt 1$. But then $x^4+x^2\gt 1$ which is out of the range of the cosine function.

Comment: I changed $cos(x)$ to $\cos(x)$ in the question. That is standard usage.

Comment: There is no explicit solution to $x=\cos(x)$

Comment: Is your book really speaking about $\sin(x^x)=1$ ? This could be the typo of the year ! The solution of  $\sin(x^x)=1$ is $\approx 1.38537$ corresponding to $x^x=\frac \pi 2$ and there is an explicit solution in terms of Lambert function.

Comment: I don't know if it is a typo. What you said is very interesting. Could you dwell more onto those results? for $\sin(x^x)$.

Comment: @JohnDouma: I don't quite get your reasoning. $-cos(x)$ is still bounded between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: @JamesWarthington Try sketching each curve. It is true that -$\cos(x)$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$ and that is precisely the point.

Comment: Yeah, that was very dumb on my part, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Newton method.

Being lazy, I started using $x_0=1+i$. This generates the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.0000000000+1.0000000000\, i \\
 1 & 0.7689041871+0.8420052018\, i \\
 2 & 0.6431803621+0.7829949990\, i \\
 3 & 0.6093767798+0.7799884053\, i \\
 4 & 0.6078614041+0.7810154976\, i \\
 5 & 0.6078632528+0.7810203081\, i
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.

Since the function is even, you have the second root by symmetry.

**Edit**

If you enjoy nightmares, let $x=a +i b$, replace and expand. This would lead you to two "nice" equations
$$a^4-6 a^2 b^2+a^2+b^4-b^2+\cos (a) \cosh (b)=0$$
$$2 a b \left(2 a^2-2 b^2+1\right)-\sin (a) \sinh (b)=0$$ corresponding to the real and imaginary parts.

You could solve them for $(a,b)$ using Newton-Raphson method.

Comment: That's great. What software do you use to compute these numerical results, Leibovici?

Comment: @JamesWarthington. Simple programming task.

Answer (score 0):

John Duma showed that
there are no real roots.

Wolfy says that
it has complex roots
$x ≈ \pm 0.607863 \pm 0.78102 i$.

Answer (score 0):

The [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) are generated from their variable by applying finite numbers of algebraic functions (algebric operations), $\exp$ and/or $\ln$.

The theorem of Lin 1983 implies that your equation cannot be solved by [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number). That means, the equation cannot be solved by applying only elementary functions.

Your equation cannot be solved by [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) either.